# MODx Gallery image size

Tags: gallery, modx, modx-revolution

I am using the Gallery component in MODx Revolution 2.0.4-pl2.

The full size image is only 500 pixels wide. This is what the tag looks like:

```
<img alt="Car" src="/MAMP/domain/assets/components/gallery/connector.php?action=web/phpthumb&w=500&h=500&zc=0&far=&q=90&src=%2Fdomain%2Fassets%2Fcomponents%2Fgallery%2Ffiles%2F2%2F8.jpg" class="">
```

Based on how I read the documentation, I should be able to change this default by adjusting the GalleryItem tag:

```
[[!GalleryItem &imageWidth=`620`]]
```

In fact, this causes the image to disappear entirely. How do I change this default width?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the correct syntax would actually be:

```
[[!GalleryItem? &imageWidth=`620`]]
```

note the missing '?'